# $|1-e^{2\pi i n z}|<1$ for $z$ in the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

If $z$ is in the upper half plane, then $|e^{2 \pi ni z}|<1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But why is also $|1-e^{2\pi i n z}|<1$?

I just get $$|1-e^{2\pi i n z}|\leq1+|e^{2 \pi ni z}|<1+1=2.$$ $$|1-e^{2\pi i n z}| < 2 $$

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Take $z=\frac{1}{2}(1+i)$, and $n=1$. Then,
$$|1-e^{2\pi n i z}|=|1-e^{\pi i(1+i)}|=|1+e^{-\pi}|>1.$$